# Cordova app that uploads my location every minute to a back-end server, even when screen is off or app is in background

Tags: cordova, networking, gps

I'm struggling writing a Cordova app for android that will keep running after the screen goes off. I'm trying background and foreground services (sometimes together) to just keep a simple loop running: Get my location, and send the JSON over TCP to a back-end server. Does anyone have a solution? I'm running Android 8.1 Oreo and I've tried putting both a foreground, background, and background-running timer npm packages in my app. No matter what I try, after ~5 minutes after shutting off my phone screen, the app stops communicating with the back-end server. I've disabled power-saving measures and I'm really stuck here. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what plugin or method have you tried? Android will definitely suspend or unload your Cordova app when minimized, no matter what.. I'm not sure if there are reliable methods to keep it running in the background, not with Cordova at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using these plugins (with cordova 9.0.0):

```
cordova-background-timer 0.0.4 "BackgroundTimer"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-foreground-service 1.1.1 "Cordova Foreground Service"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 3.0.1 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

And this JavaScript code:

```
onDeviceReady: function () {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    cordova.plugins.foregroundService.start('GPS Running', 'Background Service');

    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('activate', function () {
        console.log("Disabled webview optimizations");
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
    });
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

    var socket = io.connect('http://server.com:3000');
    socket.on('request', function (empty) {
        BackgroundGeolocation.getCurrentLocation(function (location) {
            socket.emit('location', JSON.stringify(location));
        });
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
        locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
        desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
        notificationTitle: 'Location, Location!',
        notificationText: 'enabled',
        debug: false,
        interval: 30 * 1000,
        fastestInterval: 30 * 1000,
        activitiesInterval: 30 * 1000
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', function (location) {
        // handle your locations here
        // to perform long running operation on iOS
        // you need to create background task
        //console.log("regular location:");
        //console.log(location);
        BackgroundGeolocation.startTask(function (taskKey) {
            // execute long running task
            // eg. ajax post location
            // IMPORTANT: task has to be ended by endTask
            BackgroundGeolocation.endTask(taskKey);
        });
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('stationary', function (stationaryLocation) {
        // handle stationary locations here
        //console.log("Stationary object");
        //console.log(stationaryLocation);
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log('[ERROR] BackgroundGeolocation error:', error.code, error.message);
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('start', function () {
        console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service has been started');
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('stop', function () {
        console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service has been stopped');
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('authorization', function (status) {
        console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation authorization status: ' + status);
        if (status !== BackgroundGeolocation.AUTHORIZED) {
            // we need to set delay or otherwise alert may not be shown
            setTimeout(function () {
                var showSettings = confirm('App requires location tracking permission. Would you like to open app settings?');
                if (showSetting) {
                    return BackgroundGeolocation.showAppSettings();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('background', function () {
        console.log('[INFO] App is in background');
        // you can also reconfigure service (changes will be applied immediately)
        BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
            debug: false
        });
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('foreground', function () {
        console.log('[INFO] App is in foreground');
        BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
            debug: false
        });
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('abort_requested', function () {
        console.log('[INFO] Server responded with 285 Updates Not Required');

        // Here we can decide whether we want stop the updates or not.
        // If you've configured the server to return 285, then it means the server does not require further update.
        // So the normal thing to do here would be to `BackgroundGeolocation.stop()`.
        // But you might be counting on it to receive location updates in the UI, so you could just reconfigure and set `url` to null.
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('http_authorization', () => {
        console.log('[INFO] App needs to authorize the http requests');
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.checkStatus(function (status) {
        console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service is running', status.isRunning);
        console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation services enabled', status.locationServicesEnabled);
        console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation auth status: ' + status.authorization);

        // you don't need to check status before start (this is just the example)
        if (!status.isRunning) {
            BackgroundGeolocation.start(); //triggers start on start event
        }
    });

},
```

And disabling power savings on this app, I was successful.

Also to make sure this thing works, I have the backend server send me a websocket packet every 60 seconds over the air.

It's nasty but it works. At some point I'll start chipping away at each dependency to see what the bare minimum needed is, but this works!

Comment: I'm getting `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova` – building on _iOS_

Comment: Just to clarify my post, I compiled this on Windows for Android - I can't speak for its success on iOS, and I do not own an iOS device...

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of android, Google has more and more been implementing features that kill the app off in the background. In the grand scheme, it's a good thing, it's in order to save battery life, however, this is not good news for the developer. Specifically, have a look at their documentation: [doze and adaptive battery](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

As of writing this, there are no cordova plugins that account for these features for newer android versions (doze was first introduced with android 6.0, later versions have made it harsher).

Short of writing your own plugin, there is no good answer here. Keeping your app running in the background is a feature that does (and will) require ongoing maintenance as new versions of android are released, and that is, in general, not something cordova is great at.

Cordova as a development tool is not meant for deep native features. Use cordova as a platform if you require a quick accompanying app for your main product.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, requests are somehow cashed and set on app resume - huh...

**Try this:**

Use '@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation' post template if you can or remove url and syncUrl and send your own http request in onLocation() using 'cordova-plugin-advanced-http' callback method, which sends request from native.

(Works for me now for weeks on android 7 - Samsung Galaxy)